# Wildcard SSL installation and future subdomains

Tags: ssl, wildcard, cpanel, whm

I've got one domain (eg mywebsite.com) on a WMH/CPanel environment.
I'm generating subdomains dynamically for that one domain (client1.mywebsite.com).

When going through the Wildcard SSL steps with most providers, I sometimes read I am going to have to include the subdomain details in my certificate (https://www.rapidsslonline.com/blog/setting-up-a-wildcard-ssl-on-cpanelwhm)

This would be a huge issue since I don't know which ones will be auto generated (say as my clients register) in the future, and I don't want to go and add them manually as they are created (SSL is painful enough).

My question is: Do I need to add each subdomain to the certificate manually, or is there a way to go "Wildcard is *.mydomain.com" once and for all? (CPanel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Right, You will have to install SSL on every subdomain which you have added under your cPanel. There is no automated way to install SSL on subdomain

Here are the steps for you :

> 1) In /var/cpanel/userdata/USER/ copy the example.com_SSL file to
>   $subdomain.DOMAIN.COM_SSL for each subdomain.
>
> 2)In each copied file, edit the following variables to match the
>   non-SSL subdomain: documentroot, servername, serveraliases
>
> 3) Rebuild the Apache configuration with /scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
>
> 4)Restart the Apache server with /scripts/restartsrv_httpd